# Splitting an array of strings in Java using .split

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have browsed through questions similar to mine already on here, but have not found anything that will work for me.

Essentially what I have to do is read a file full of strings line by line, print them line by line and then word by word. I would like to accomplish this using .split to create an array of each individual string.

For instance, my file reads:
The fat cat was black
The cow jumped over the moon
I came to say hello world

etc.

I have figured out how to read the file and print the file line by line, but I cannot figure out how to print it word by word. Each of these 3 are in their own functions, so I'm not sure if that plays any role in where something is placed.

This is what I have so far in my method:

```
static public void printWords( String [ ] arr, int count )
{
    String [] s2 = arr[0].split( " " ); 

    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(  s2 [i] );
    }

    System.out.println();  
}
```

However, this is giving me an error. I switched around a couple things, but each time it prints either just the lines or stops at a certain point. The only thing I have in main is my method call pertaining to this, which is not the problem. If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

"Count" in my code is the number of lines in the file I am reading. So for this, it is 3.

I have tweaked the code to get what I need, however it only prints the first sentence.

```
String [] s2 = arr[0].split( " " );
    for (int j = 0 ; j < count ; j++)
    {

        for( int i = 3; i < s2.length; i++)
        {

        System.out.print(  s2 [i] + " " );
        }
    System.out.println();

    }

}
```

For example, this only prints 
The fat cat was black
And then ends. I am trying to construct another loop around it (as demonstrated by my code) but it ends up just printing "The fat cat was black" 3 times rather than moving to the next line of the file.

Comment: What error do you get? Your error also seems to come from count. Try s2.length instead of count

Comment: When you're iterating over `s2`, why use the count as the `for` loop condition? Why not `s2.length`?

Comment: Please state your output and/or errors so we can better help you.

Comment: If this is Java 5 or higher, don't read line-by-line; use a `Scanner`. ([tag:java-util-scanner])

Comment: I get an exception in main, and I forgot to mention this is a homework problem so I am unable to change the method call/definition. This is why I assumed I should use count since it is called.

Comment: When I use s2.length, it only prints The fat cat was black. Perhaps I need to put it in another loop to read each line?

Comment: does your homework say, what `count` should be used for?

Comment: `The fat cat was black` RACIST!      ;D

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
static public void printWords(String [ ] arr)
{

  for(String s : arr) {
      String[] s2 = s.split(" ");
      for(String results : s2) {
          System.out.println(results);
      }
  }

}
```

With this you don't need the count variable either.

Comment: I forgot to state that this was a homework problem, and unfortunately I cannot change the method call so I'm forced to deal with the count variable.

Comment: @S12 Ah, ok.  Does it say what count is supposed to be used for?  Using an external variable for iterating over an array is always more dangerous than using the internal array size.  Looks like your professor is carrying over a habit from C/C++ of passing array size in, unless count means something different.

Comment: It is used to count the actual number of lines in the file, because it was originally initialized to max and count is used to get rid of empty space in the array.

Comment: S2 is a set of words from the first value in your array arr.  Count is the number of lines in your text.  There is no reason for those numbers to match, is there?  What is in arr?

Comment: If you want to avoid blank lines due to leading or trailing spaces, you might want to call trim() on the arr before splitting it.

Answer (score 0):

it could be an error with your for loop stopping at count instead of (array.length || count)

Answer (score 0):

The count can only be used for the number of lines which make sense if this is a homework problem.  You were close to the solution but you had your split statement in the wrong place.

The String array arr contains the strings from the file and the count is the number of lines taken the from the file so it is a limit for the iterator that will go through the arr array.  You had the right idea by using a seperate iterator to go through the s2 array as it only contained the words from a single line from arr.

Try this:

```
static public void printWords( String [ ] arr, int count )
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < count ; j++)
    {
        String [] s2 = arr[j].split( " " );
        for( int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(  s2 [i] + " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically split by white space.

```
public void split() {
            ArrayList<String> myArray=new ArrayList<>();
            myArray.add("The fat cat was black");
            myArray.add("The cow jumped over the moon");
            for (String strLine : myArray) {
                String[] strWord = strLine.split("[\\s']");
                for (String s : strWord) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }

        }
```

here `[\\s']` represents a white space, tabs, line breaks.